# Photoshop Oil Paint Filter grayed out (Geforce GTX 1070)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

The oil paint filter is not available on my system (grayed out) even though I have a powerful graphic card, the newest Nvidia drivers and walked through all the available troubleshooting steps. Anybody have this issue as well or does the 1070 just not work with the oil paint filter?

Comment: Didn't they remove the oil paint filter?

Comment: Its visible in my UI, but grayed out

Comment: @Scott it was reintroduced in CC2015

Comment: @ChristianStrang , just to make sure, do you have ``Use Graphics Processor`` and ``Use Open CL`` option turned ON in Performance Preferences?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy: Use OpenCL is grayed out, I also tried all the troubleshooting I could get my hands on, but OpenCL stays disabled :/ https://i.imgur.com/1vUDcQO.png

Comment: I guess that's the reason. Maybe posting on Adobe forum with more info about your system/what you've tried will be more helpful.

Comment: If you're on windows, I'd suggest you try uninstalling current drivers with [Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/) and then install new drivers. I've heard that if you have remnants of old drivers in your machine, PS may sort of find false information about your graphics card an disable the open Open CL option... or something like that... Might be worth a shot. Uninstalling with DDU might not be necessary since Nvidia has the "clean" install, but DDU is more thorough so I'd just straight up try that.

Comment: Joonas you were right, after cleaning my system in safe mode with DDU and reinstalling the NVIDIA drivers, use OpenCL is now selectable, thank you! (if you convert your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as solved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on windows, I'd suggest you try uninstalling current drivers with [Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/) and then install new drivers.

I've heard that if you have remnants of old drivers in your machine, PS may sort of find false information about your graphics and disable features... or something like that... Might be worth a shot. Uninstalling with DDU might not be necessary since Nvidia has the "clean" install, but DDU is more thorough so I'd just straight up try that.

---

Also, it only works in RGB Color mode.

`Image > Mode > RGB Color`.